# Data binding between two textboxes in different windows using WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, textbox

There are a number of similar queries on the internet from which I have written the following code. But it does not seem to be working.

There are two windows: Mainwindow and Window1.

- Mainwindow has a textbox named RUNTIME
- Window1 has a textbox STOPTIME.

When a button on mainwindow is pressed window1 opens.

I want to create a binding between the two text boxes such that if I write something in RUNTIME and open window 1, stop time should have the same value. And when I open window1 and write something in STOPTIME it should immediately be reflected in RUNTIME.

Please note that on the main window there is no enter button. Just as anything is written in textbox RUNTIME, it is saved in a variable Time.

**Main Window**

```
     <Window> 
    .
    .
    .           
        <TextBox x:Name="RUNTIME"  Width="120" Text="{Binding runtime,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" /> 


<MenuItem Header="Menu"> 
<MenuItem Header="SubMenu" Click="set_config_param" StaysOpenOnClick="True"/> 
</MenuItem>                      
    .
    .
    .             
        </Window>
```

**Window1**

```
     <Window>   
.
.
.                  
    <TextBox x:Name="STOPTIME" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="145,27,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Text="{Binding runtime, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
.
.
.                   
    </Window>
```

The Time variable is used to store runtime/stoptime. I have created a separate class for this.

```
public class Time : INotifyPropertyChanged
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private string _runtime;

        private void OnPropertyChanged(String property)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
            }
        }

        public string runtime
        {
            get
            {
                return _runtime;
            }
            set
            {
                _runtime = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("runtime");
            }
        }  
    }
```

Now the C# code.

**Main Window**

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
        {
           Time _Time = new Time();

            public MainWindow()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                RUNTIME.DataContext = _Time;
    }

private void set_config_param(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
                {

                    bool isWindowOpen=false;
foreach (Window w in Application.current.Windows)

{
if (w is Window1)
{
isWindowOpen = true;
w.Activate();
}
if (!isWindowOpen)
{
Window1 newwindow = new Window();
newwindow.Show();
}
}}
    }
```

**Window1**

```
   public partial class Window1 : Window
        {
            Time _Time = new Time();

            public Window1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();

               STOPTIME.DataContext = _Time;
            }

            private void OK_Window1_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {

                _Time.runtime = STOPTIME.Text;
            }

}
```

The problem I have understood so far is that I have failed to instantiate the same instance of time in both the forms. How can I do that? Where exactly should i change my code.

Comment: The code you show binds to `FirstName`, a property that does not exist in any of the other code you posted (there's only the `runtime` property). It _also_ may be that you've failed to use the same model object in both windows (depending on how `_Time` is initialized), but you haven't provided a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem, so it's not possible to say whether that, or anything else, is also in fact wrong.

Comment: i have done the necessary changes and apologise for the inconvenience. but what else may i include to make sure that the problem is completely described here? the problem has only occurred because i have tried to simplify the variable names etc for ease of comprehension.

Comment: in your MainWindow, you are creating a new instance of `_Time`. Next in Window1, you're creating a new instance of `_Time` again. Try modifying `public Window1()` to `public Window1(Time _Time)`, and inject the same instance via `Window1 newwindow = new Window1(this._Time)`

Comment: yes!!!! this is the correct ans! solved my problem exactly! thanks a lot!...plz post it as ans so tht i can mark it!!

Comment: @sadia_123k: we would like questions and comments here to be as readable as possible for future readers. Given that Stack Overflow is also not a chatroom, would you mind using real words? "Please" instead of "pls", "that" instead of "tht", etc. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copying a comment from @ jayars:
in your MainWindow, you are creating a new instance of _Time. Next in Window1, you're creating a new instance of _Time again. Try modifying public Window1() to public Window1(Time _Time), and inject the same instance via Window1 newwindow = new Window1(this._Time)

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that you are doing it wrong. Since your goal is to **share** same object across different windows, it **must be** stored somewhere, where each of those windows can access. So the easiest way to implement this is using Singleton design pattern.
You can bind to static class as following:
`...Text={Binding Path=<Path_on_the_Singleton_object>, Source={x:Static namespace:StaticClass.<Static_Singleton_Property>}}...`

Comment: doesnt seem to be working..or i mightve some syntax error

Comment: You can google and fix the syntax and implementation details. I showed you a solution in general.